# Buggy `<select>` and `<input>` elements with Bootstrap and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bootstrap-4

I have a `<select>` that I am trying to use with my react project.  It is very buggy and I am having a bit of difficulty understanding where the source is.  I have searched numerous posts, tried some of the suggestions, however none are working in my case.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchDoctors } from '../actions/index';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectButtonName = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      type: '',
      location: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    this.props.history.push('/doctors/result');
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.fetchDoctors(this.state);

  }
  onSelect(event) {
    this.setState({ type: event.currentTarget.textContent });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
        <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
          <div className="col-8">
            <div className="jumbotron">
              <h2 className="display-4">We Are Here For You</h2>
              <p className="lead">Find Help</p>
              <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} action="/doctors/result">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="input-group">
                    <div className="input-group-prepend">

                      <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.selectedValue} name="type" className="custom-select">
                        <option name="type" value="Therapist" selected>Therapist</option>
                        <option name="type" value="Psychiatrist">Psychiatrist</option>
                        <option name="type" value="All">All</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      aria-label="Text input with dropdown button"
                      placeholder="Search by City"
                      name="location"
                      id="locationSearch"
                      value={this.state.location}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" role="button">
                  Search
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchDoctors }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchBar);
```

The problems that I am having are the following:

1) My input text always seems to be one character short of what I enter.  For example, if I type the word 'Honolulu', by the time I type the final 'u', if I console log `this.state`, as I have in my `handleChange` function, it simply reads 'Honolul'

2) I need to select from my select dropdown numerous times before it actually registers that I have made a selection.  Once it starts to recognize that I am actually making selections, the actual selected value is pretty random and rarely what I actually selected.

3) I am not able to set the default selection.  "Therapist" is selected by default, as I have it set as `selected`.  However if I simply submit, "Therapist" is not sent as state.  As I write this I am beginning to think that perhaps I simply need to set `this.state={type:'Therapist'}` by default in the constructor so perhaps I have just answered my own question on this one.

Mahalo for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because you are logging it before the last state update. After the last setState your handleChange function is not invoked hence you don't see the last letter. Even if you do this after setState call line, it can't catch up the state. To log your state it is a better idea to do it in render.
2. At the current code you are not even using onSelect for select. Change it, and use event.target.value instead of event.currentTarget.textContent. Edit: As you mentioned in the comments, if you don't want to separate handle logic, you can do this together as shown in the current code.
3. Yes, you can do this. Even in the official documentation this is explained as you think: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Here is a slightly cleaner working version of your app:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    type: 'Therapist',
    location: ''
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return( 
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} action="/doctors/result">
          <select name="select" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.type} name="type" className="custom-select">
            <option value="Therapist">Therapist</option>
            <option value="Psychiatrist">Psychiatrist</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
          </select>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            aria-label="Text input with dropdown button"
            placeholder="Search by City"
            name="location"
            id="locationSearch"
            value={this.state.location}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer and the code.  Unfortunately its still the same even with your code.   For the first point, I also thought the same thing before I posted so I put the `console.log` after the setState.  Still the same though.  Regarding the onSelect, I found that I didnt actually need it as I should be able to do the same with the `handleChange`, therefore I never actually call the `onSelect`.  Thanks for pointing out my last point.

Comment: Ok I have gone back through again with your code and it does actually work after a few refreshes.  Mahalo again for your help.

Comment: For the first question: Even you put it after the setState call, you can't see the change. Last setState updates your state, re-render your component. But, console.log can't catch up with state change. For the second question, if you don't want to separate select change, of course you can do it together. Just name your select and change the related part. I will edit my answer according to this.